# How to use printf function in DOSBOX

Tags: assembly, x86

I am learning assembly and  just came to know that you can't run 16 bit read mode code from 32 bit linux. You have to set proper environment to run 16 bit code from 32 bit Linux.

So I installed the DOSBOX on Ubuntu and am able to run 16 bit code, but I am into another problem now. I wanted to use the `printf` function from DOSBOX. Below is the code:

```
section .data
x   dw   "value is =%d"

section .text
extern printf
global main

main:
    push  x
    call  printf
    add   sp,2
    ret
```

But when I assemble this code, I am getting the error below:

```
    binary output format does not support external references
```

Now I would like to know what is the proper way to do a `printf` call in the DOSBOX environment.

Comment: `printf` is part of `libc`, which you don't have in DOS. You'll have to write your own `printf` implementation, or find one that works with DOS and the assembler you're using.

Comment: And if `printf` was available, you aren't passing enough parameters since you pass the format string, but not the integer value the format string requires.

Comment: it sounds like you need a C compiler (or at least the stdlib) for DOS. Some are linked from [the FreeDOS devel page](http://www.freedos.org/software/?cat=devel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best advice in this situation is to stop trying to write 16bit real mode code. If you try to learn assembly language, it is more easy when you are working in 32bit protected mode environment.

Use Linux or Windows in your choice. I would suggest also to try [FASM](http://flatassembler.net) as an assembler. It is very powerful and beginner friendly. There are tons of example code and good community.

Comment: Thanks @johnfound for your response . I would like to ask you couple of things.1)Does modern day bootloader make use of real mode code?? 2)If we have to bring up x86 board how much essential to know of programming in Real mode??

Comment: @AmitSinghTomar Yes, bootloader uses real mode code, but any decent OS switches to protected mode as early as possible. 2. If mentioned board is designed by you and there is no need to keep compatibility with PC architecture, the only decent way is to switch to protected mode as early as possible as well. But, note, that if you are beginner in assembly language, you simply can't do neither 1 nor 2. You need to learn a lot, before starting work on these tasks.

Comment: Thanks @Johnfound for all your help . I was just simply asking whatever doubt I have in above comment. I knew its just beginning for me and I am not going to work in any of thing in near future.

Answer (score 1):

Besides what others have mentioned... You want to assemble this with Nasm's "-f obj" format, not "-f bin" (which is what the error message looks like). Your format string probably wants to be `db`, not `dw`. Outside of Linux, you probably want an underscore on `main` and `printf`. You can write your source without underscores, and use `--prefix _` on Nasm's command line to add leading underscores to anything `global` or `extern`. If you're using OpenWatcom C, it wants trailing underscores(!) - use `--postfix _` instead. (note: one of the few Nasm options that needs two hyphens).

After assembling this to "myprog.obj", you'll need to link it against the C library. Details will differ with which compiler/linker/library you're using.

If you're just trying to read your MBR, it is probably easier to write 32-bit Linux code to do this. A different question, however.  Either way, Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks Frank Kotler for your help .Would you also like to address couple of my doubt which I asked above .

Comment: Uhhh... bootloader? I can't add too much to what John Found has said. I would observe that in the "good old days" plenty of people learned real mode programming without being "experts" first. There's a lot to learn. You have to keep your segment registers in order (can ignore 'em in pmode, usually), and you're limited to 64k segments (you can get a LOT of code in 64k). The main difficulty with a bootloader is that we can't ASSume a lot that an OS would have done for us. You'd need to learn BIOS interrupts, since neither dos ints nor printf is available. We're a long way from printf in dosbox!